# Terraform aws_s3_bucket_object not triggered by archive_file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have built the following terraform code:

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_dependencies_bundle" {
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.lambda_dependencies
  ]

  output_path = "${local.function_build_folder_path}/build/${local.function_s3_object_key}.zip"
  excludes    = ["${local.function_build_folder_path}/build/*"]
  source_dir  = local.function_build_folder_path
  type        = "zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lambda_dependencies_bucket" {
  bucket = local.function_s3_bucket
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "lambda_dependencies_upload" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_dependencies_bucket.id
  key    = "${local.function_s3_object_key}.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.lambda_dependencies_bundle.output_path
}
```

The null_resource.lambda_dependencies is triggered by a file change and just builds all of my code to `local.function_build_folder_path`.
Everytime the null_resource changes, the `archive_file.lambda_dependencies_bundle` rebuilds (correct behavior!).

But other than expected, the `aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda_dependencies_upload` is not triggered by the rebuild of the archive_file.

How can I achieve a reupload of my archive_file on a rebuild?

Comment: the e-tag way works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add [etag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object#etag):

> Triggers updates when the value changes.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "lambda_dependencies_upload" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_dependencies_bucket.id
  key    = "${local.function_s3_object_key}.zip"
  source = data.archive_file.lambda_dependencies_bundle.output_path
  etag = data.archive_file.lambda_dependencies_bundle.output_md5
}
```

Comment: The `filemd5` function is only for files that pre-exist as part of the configuration, but can get a similar effect dynamically with `etag = data.archive_file.lambda_dependencies_bundle.output_md5`